# Neural network in TF 2.0: cannot train in float64 precision

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I have a working neural network (built in Tensorflow 2.0 with the Keras API) which I trained using `float32` precision (default precision). Now I want to train with float64 precision. I enable it with `tensorflow.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64)` before starting the execution of the neural network. The training starts, but at the last batch of the first epoch I get the following error:

```
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\DL_Reconstruction\train_stage_1.py", line 49, in train_vae
    validation_split=1/19, callbacks=callbacks) # CHANGE val split
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 674, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 449, in model_iteration
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 298, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1614, in on_epoch_end
    self._log_weights(epoch)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1696, in _log_weights
    self._log_weight_as_image(weight, weight_name, epoch)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1721, in _log_weight_as_image
    summary_ops_v2.image(weight_name, w_img, step=epoch)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\summary_ops_v2.py", line 820, in image
    return summary_writer_function(name, tensor, function, family=family)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\summary_ops_v2.py", line 730, in summary_writer_function
    should_record_summaries(), record, _nothing, name="")
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\smart_cond.py", line 54, in smart_cond
    return true_fn()
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\summary_ops_v2.py", line 723, in record
    with ops.control_dependencies([function(tag, scope)]):
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\summary_ops_v2.py", line 818, in function
    name=scope)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_summary_ops.py", line 654, in write_image_summary
    name=name, ctx=_ctx)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_summary_ops.py", line 698, in write_image_summary_eager_fallback
    attrs=_attrs, ctx=_ctx, name=name)
  File "Z:\Z_MASTER\Envs\p37_new_clone\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of double is not in the list of allowed values: uint8, float, half
    ; NodeDef: {{node WriteImageSummary}}; Op<name=WriteImageSummary; signature=writer:resource, step:int64, tag:string, tensor:T, bad_color:uint8 -> ; attr=max_images:int,default=3,min=1; attr=T:type,default=DT_FLOAT,allowed=[DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT, DT_HALF]; is_stateful=true> [Op:WriteImageSummary] name: enc_0_conv/kernel_0/

Process finished with exit code 1
```

To cut a long story short, I guess the last line of the error message would be the most helpful in finding the bug:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of double is not in the list of allowed values: uint8, float, half
```

I tried to solve this issue by changing the `dtype` parameter of the layers to `float64` the following way (only snippets):

```
conv = Conv2D(..., dtype='float64')(input)
...
output = ReLU(dtype='float64')(input)
...
lat_var = Lambda(... dtype='float64')([z_mean, z_log_var])
...
```

The code crashes at this line:

```
 history = model.fit(x=images, y=images, epochs=200, batch_size=32,
                        validation_split=1/19, callbacks=callbacks)
```

with `images` being a numpy array of type `float64`, which was achieved by `images = images.astype('float64')`.

Does anybody know how I can train in `float64` precision?

Comment: The bug disappeared after commenting out two Tensorboard callbacks which were called at the end of each epoch: `TensorBoard(log_dir='logs_1', profile_batch=0, histogram_freq=1, write_images=True),
TensorBoard(log_dir=GLOBAL.tb_dir, profile_batch=0, histogram_freq=1, write_images=True)`

Comment: Setting the `write_images` flag in the tensorboard callback to `False' solves the problem.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, which you will be able to accept yourself after 48 hours from posting the question. As is, people will start reading here trying to help you, before reaching the comments and realize that you have already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the bug were two Tensorboard callbacks which were called at the end of each epoch to log the training. To be more specific, setting the argument `write_images=False` of the Tensorboard callback solves the problem.

Here is the full working code for the callbacks

```
TensorBoard(log_dir='logs_1', profile_batch=0, histogram_freq=1, write_images=True)
TensorBoard(log_dir='current_logs', profile_batch=0, histogram_freq=1, write_images=True)
```